Sent money to rent an apartment, landlord delaying refund with excuses. Is this a scam?
So we were looking for an apartment and we sent 1500 to a person that said he would rent the apartment but then he said that his previous tenant had corona so we can't rent the apartment. From that time he is answering our SMS messages and sometimes our calls. He asked a few times do we want the refund and we said yes, he told us that he would transfer us the money through ACH transfer but that didn't work, then he told us he will meet with us in person but his schedule is full so he can't. Now he offered us to send our money through Zelle as we did. Is it a scam, should I report him or not?

Did you see the apartment with them? Did you see the actual apartment?

Did you see the Zelle transfer on your bank statement? Zelle transfers are almost immediate, and should appear on your bank account right away. Anything other than the transfer showing up in your actual bank means it's a scam.

I mean you know where they live right...

@Asleepace only if they actually saw the apartment from the inside. Scams sometimes include renting out apartments one does not own, if the prospective renter agrees to pay money based on only pictures or videos of the apartment (easily faked)

I find it highly unusual to send money without having a contract first. That's not how it usually works, at least where I live...

Have you met them in person already? How far from each other are you currently? "Schedule is full" is a pretty lame excuse unless you live very far from each other - he can always make time to meet someone for 2 mins even if it means you call to them. It also seems very odd that he would decide not to rent an apartment just because the previous tenant had Covid - surely that would just delay the move-in date for a week or so?

Is he saying that he can't rent it now because the previous tenant is currently sick with Covid, and thus is unable to move out as expected? Or is he saying that the apartment is somehow no longer fit to be rented because a previous tenant at one time had Covid while living there?

@infinitezero In cities with a very difficult housing market, renters are under pressure to pay right away, so as not to miss the opportunity. Even without a contract, or keys, or meeting the landlord, or even seeing the property. Scammers love it.

Please note that "seeing the apartment" is not a guarantee of things being on the level, only a strong indicator.  We've had a number of cases locally where the perps had rented an apartment and were thus fully capable of showing it.  Advertise it , schedule a bunch of visits and take the corresponding down payments and you can do quite well.  One such event came to light when a number of strangers found themselves together in a lobby, all waiting for the keys to the same apartment...  I walked away from one where the owner was insistent on cash over cheques for example.

Not an answer, but a suggestion: If you are concerned that this may be a scam, you should independently look up who the owners and/or rental agents are for that building and contact them directly, asking them to confirm that you are dealing with them rather than somebody pretending to be them.

Everything about that says "scam".
Corona virus does not last very long without a host to live in.  the apartment could be left empty for a few days and it would be safe.
The scammer pretends that they have tried to refund you, but mysteriously the refund doesn't work.
And they can't possibly meet you to hand back the money.
Before long, they will stop responding at all.
If you really know who they are, you could report them.  But you have probably lost your money.

I don't know if there was an 'official' scam name but for a while people were renting out Airbnb apartments and then pretending to be the landlord and taking deposits only to vanish later.

I initially read the "previous tenant had corona" thing to mean that the previous tenant couldn't travel, and was thus still there. No idea if that's true, but it might provide a more reasonable explanation for refusing the let.

@psmears - It's possible, but I'd expect that to be more "you can't rent it yet" or really "you can't move in yet".  Refunding because the previous tenant was still there seems a bit overkill unless the renter wants to cancel the deal.

@Bobson: Yeah - my reading was that this was a short-term (AirBnb-style) lease, in which case refunding would make more sense. Agin, no idea if this is true!

And likely he asked for additional details about you to "try the refund again"....

Plus, refunding the money the way it was originally sent should be the FIRST way to "try" the refund, not the last resort...

The tenant doesn’t have Covid. They just pay their rent every month to their landlord. On the other hand, there is a scammer who pretends to be the landlord, taking your money and eventually will disappear.

Nothing about this screams scam to me, but it could go either way.
If you have never met this landlord in person or been given access to view the apartment that makes it more likely to be a scam.
Despite other answers, lots of people are still getting COVID. That by itself is not a red flag.

Agreed. It certainly could be a scam, but it also could be legitimate human incompetence. If you do get the money back through Zelle, that it wasn't a scam.

Seems a bit suspicious - He's just going to let it lay dormant forever because someone had Covid in it? Surely that would just delay the moving in, not prevent it altogether.

@komodosp I don't see where you get "forever"  from the description of the problem.

@keshlam, outside of a few specific environments, the COVID-19 virus only lingers in the environment for a few days; turn up the heat, and you can get the place safe by the time you're done with the paperwork.

I still don't see forever. I'm also not certain that this isn't a misphrased "prior tenant is ill and I'm compassionately letting them extend their lease." Either I am misreading this, or people are reading things into it which has not been stated.

@keshlam - I was kind of speaking figuratively when I said "forever".  I meant, the landlord has decided not to let out the apartment and to forego the rental income, rather than just delay the move-in date. He's talking about returning the deposit / first month's rent which implies an entire cancellation of the agreement. (and may be take longer than the Covid takes to die out!)

"prior tenant is ill and I'm compassionately letting them extend their lease." - perhaps, but the OP hasn't said this at all (if so then the original question needs this clarification!) I believe this may be reading into it what has not been stated

@komodosp: That's exactly the problem. We don't have enough data to do more than guess at this point. There is justification for concern, but not for a solid conclusion.

There are some concerning things about your post but the main scammy hallmark hasn't been hit yet...

So we were looking for an apartment and we sent 1500 to a person that said he would rent the apartment

You sent money without seeing the apartment in person? Oh boy, is this normal nowadays? I haven't rented a new place in almost 15 years.

but then he said that his previous tenant had corona so we can't rent the apartment.

If the tenant is on their deathbed then it's understandable that the landlord isn't looking to kick them out quite yet. If the tenant merely has the sniffles then this is a weird roadblock.

From that time he is answering our SMS messages and sometimes our calls. He asked a few times do we want the refund and we said yes,

I can't imagine why this requires asking more than once. They are either scamming or truly in disarray.

he told us that he would transfer us the money through ACH transfer but that didn't work,

Whoa, whoa, whoa, you supplied them your banking info? It's certainly weird that the refund method is different than the original payment method, Zelle.
Albeit, not inherently dangerous but scammers usually try to use this as a springboard to ask for your bank login details at some point.

then he told us he will meet with us in person but his schedule is full so he can't.

Weird, but okay.

Now he offered us to send our money through Zelle as we did.

Yes, have them refund the money via Zelle.
If the money comes from an account different than the one you sent money to initially then this would raise a red flag; it could indicate a different victim sending you money. If they refund more than what you paid then it would also be a red flag.

Is it a scam, should I report him or not?

It's hard to say right now. If you receive the money successfully then never contact this person again.
Scammers trick customers via Zelle usually with something along the lines of "You need a pro/business account so pay money at this obscure URL to unlock your funds."
I whole-heartedly recommend fully reviewing https://www.zellepay.com/safety-education/video-how-avoid-online-marketplace-scam

"Whoa, whoa, whoa, you supplied them your banking info? Albeit, not inherently dangerous ..."  It's not?   There's any number of ways having that information could be used for nefarious purposes.

@JasonGoemaat Most of us have written a check in our lifetime...

@JasonGoemaat The "Whoa, whoa, whoa" refers to it being weird that the landlord is taking a different refund path than the original payment.

and have you had your sister-in-law use that to pay her credit card?

@JasonGoemaat huh?

"Yes, have them refund the money via Zelle." I'd just note that it's very likely that said refund will either a) be from some other victim and eventually reversed or b) another scam on a fake-Zelle.

@ceejayoz Thanks, I made note of that in my answer. The fake-Zelle scenario is covered in my closing paragraphs since that is the most common hallmark. Legitimate Zelle transfers are almost impossible to reverse so if OP gets a victim's legitimate money then only their conscience would lead them to give it back.

@MonkeyZeus Zelle transferrs are reversible if they were unauthorized, like if someone's account is compromised to send OP's refund. The scammers will use some poor victim's Zelle to send money, which will get reversed, leaving OP in the shit. https://www.zellepay.com/safety-education/fraud-scams-overview "Because you did NOT authorize a payment, you are typically able to get your money back after reporting the incident."

@ceejayoz I think that's why scammers prefer to not use compromised accounts and instruct the victim to voluntarily send the money.

I rented an apartment 3 1/2 years ago and I definitely looked at it, met the landlord in person, and had a signed contract before paying the deposit.
